# Sending datas to multiple tables - CakePHP 3.2

Tags: php, cakephp, frameworks, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to do a chat system, I'm having troubles with it, my ideia is the following:
When the user send a message, this message has to be saved in 2 tables in my database... But it isn't working, the message is saving in only one table.

**public function sendMessage()**

```
    $data = $this->request->data();
    $sessionId = $data['idSession'];
    $userId = $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.id');
    $msg = $data['message'];
    $typeMessage = $data['type'];
    $messageTable = TableRegistry::get('messages');
    $messageAllTable = TableRegistry::get('mensage_alls');
    if ($typeMessage == 1)
    {      
        $message['session_private_id'] = $sessionId;
    }
    else
    {
        $message['session_id'] = $sessionId;
    }
    $message = array_merge($message, array(
        'user_id' => $userId,
        'message' => $msg,
        'created_at' => new \DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")),
    ));
    $messageEntity = $messageTable->newEntity();
    $messageEntity = $messageTable->patchEntity($messageEntity, $message, ['validate' => false]);
    $resposta = $messageTable->save($messageEntity);
    $this->response->body($resposta);
    return $this->response;
```

I'm a beginner in CakePHP, so, don't need to call me a dumb.
Thanks since now. And sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the reason why you'd want to duplicate the data (it doesn't sound like a good thing generally speaking), the reason it doesn't work is you never saved it to the 2nd table. You need to call something at minimum like:

```
$resposta = $messageTable->save($messageEntity);
$messageCopy = $messageAllTable->newEntity($messageEntity);
$respostaCopy = $messageAllTable->save($messageCopy);
$this->response->body($resposta && $respostaCopy);
```

If you meant you want to to always automatically copy to a secondary table, then you could instead add a [Behavior](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors.html) to the main Message Table. For example, a bare-bones version would look like:

In MessageTable.php:

```
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;

class MessageTable extends Table
{

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        // Add this line
        $this->addBehavior('CopyMessage');
    }
}
```

And create a **src/Model/Behavior/CopyMessageBehavior.php:**

```
namespace App\Model\Behavior;

use Cake\ORM\Behavior;

class CopyMessageBehavior extends Behavior
{
    public function copyMessage(Entity $entity)
    {
        $messageAllTable = TableRegistry::get('mensage_alls');
        $messageCopy =messageAllTable->newEntity($messageEntity);
        $messageAllTable->save($messageCopy);
    }
   public function beforeSave(Event $event, EntityInterface $entity)
    {
        $this->copyMessage($entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd also discourage turning off validation. Maybe re-evaluate why you're duplicating data and see if there's a cleaner table structure possible (there probably is). The return line is also unnecessary in your example.

Comment: Oh and one more thing - instead of manually tracking the date_created, check out the built in [Timestamp Behavior](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/timestamp.html)

Comment: Hey ahoffner, thanks for your answer. The reason is: There's a person who's streaming a video (like Twitch, for example), and also have some people watching the stream. In my chat system, when the Streamer send a message, this message will appears for everybody, but when a viewer send a message, will only appears the message for the streamer, and not for everybody. For this reason I want to send a message to 2 different tables, when the streamer send a message go to: "messages" and "message_alls", when a viewer send a message, I just want this message in "messages" table. Do you got it?

Comment: I'd still probably use a single table for that - since they're all just messages it'd be cleaner to just store them together. Filter the view of these messages instead. You could join on the User_id, and filter messages for "viewers" to only those of the Streamer that way, potentially.

Comment: OK, I'll try this way, thanks for your help, if something goes wrong, I back here to tell you. I prefer in your way since begin, but my boss that want this way... So, what can I do?